# Check if class "respects" interface without implementing it

Tags: java, interface

I would like to check if a class implements all the methods of a specific interface without directly implementing it.

i.e. Consider the interface

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public String myMethod();
}
```

and the following classes:

A implements the interface, so has the method myMethod

```
public class A implements MyInterface {
    public String myMethod() {
        return "something";
    }
}
```

B doesn't implement the interface, but has the method myMethod

```
public class B {
    public String myMethod() {
        return "something else";
    }
}
```

So `MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class);` is `true` and   `MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class);` is `false`. I'm looking for a method returning true for both classes.

Using reflection, for each class, I can loop over the methods of the interface and check if it is implemented in the class. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Reflection is a way to go

Comment: I'm curious what you're trying to achieve here. Java isn't really a duck-typed language so what's the value? I mean, implementing all the methods which some interface specifies doesn't mean the class can interact in any meaningful way with users of the interface.

Comment: @sisyphus I generated a web service client and I got many classes (return types of the web methods) with the same methods. Since the web service client will be generated again many times, I prefer to avoid editing the generated classes.

Comment: It is safer, even for 100 classes, to put implements MyInterface. There, your code will be more robust, for the new ones .... Or use reflection. Not too hard.

Comment: If you do this via reflection you've got a significant amount of work involved - the signatures need to match but they don't need to be exact matches. So, you have to be able to deal with covariant return types, method overriding through varying number of arguments, widening/narrowing of argument types and widening / narrowing of exception handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot do that without reflection.

And...

**Interfaces are contracts**

While you might be able to figure out that B indeed has methods that have the same name as those in `MyInterface`, you have no way to tell, if they actually *do the same thing*.

By implementing an interface (as B should have), you not only implement the methods of that interface, but you *commit on providing the results* in a way that is intended. Having a method of the same name with same parameters will just not do in that situation.